# Export Google sheet and upload to Sharepoint

Tags: google-apps-script, sharepoint, google-sheets, sharepoint-online

I am using Google Sheets to create files for customers.  These are then exported and sent out I would like these to be uploaded to sharepoint and was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way to do it.

The script I use currently is as below:

```js
function CreatePDF() {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheetName = "Agreement";
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sh = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Input");
  var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents();
  var folderName =parentFolder.next().getId();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderName); 
  var numf = sourceSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("AgreementSheet").getValue();
  var anof = numf.split("/",2);
  
  var pdfRange = sh.getRange("I19");
  var pdfName = pdfRange.getValue();

  // export url
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+sourceSpreadsheet.getId()+'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=A4'                           
  + '&portrait=true'                     
  + '&fitw=true' 
  + '&top_margin=0.00'              
  + '&bottom_margin=0.00'          
  + '&left_margin=0.00'             
  + '&right_margin=0.00'  
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' 
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' 
  + '&fzr=false'                         
  + '&gid='+sourceSheet.getSheetId();    

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName+'.pdf');

  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  var url1 = newFile.getDownloadUrl();

  Logger.log(url1);
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url1+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Downloading ..." );
  history()
  clearContents()
  var pdfUrl = DriveApp.getFileById(newFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  Logger.log(pdfUrl);
  return true;
  sh.showSheet();
}
```

Before when I have worked with excel you could upload a file like below:
`https://xxx.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/group/folder/` then add the file name which creates the below string:
`https://xxx.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/group/folder/file-name.pdf`

I tried doing a similar trick with Apps script as below:

```js
var shp = 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/group/folder/' + url1;

//then add this to the redirect script:
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+shp+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Downloading ..." );
```

Using the second chunk of code in my question, I can Download the pdf by opening the download URL (using the function `.getDownloadUrl()` for the `newFile`) or I can open sharepoint by using the `var shp = 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/group/folder/')` - what I don't know how to do is essentially download the file and put it in Sharepoint

Comment: Yep, first thing I did.  Not helpful at all

Comment: Describe the problem. Error quotes, messages anything else.  Your question provides a code and doesn't even say it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is what I have tried doesn't work.  The script runs and opens the SharePoint folder in a new tab but doesn't download the pdf into that folder like I want it

Comment: So it downloads a pdf just not into the folder you want?

Comment: Ok. That's the description of the problem. You should [edit]  that into your question. I am not aware of the trick  you mention in your question or sharepoint in general (Not many attempt to actually connect Google and Microsoft). In any case, after a bit of research, IMO, Your best bet is to use Sharepoint apis and use [tag:urlfetch] to post the data.